# Inclusão de `final` pelo Eclipse após salvar arquivo

Tags: java, eclipse

Quando estou trabalhando em alguma class e salvo o arquivo alterado, por alguma razão o Eclipse adiciona `final` em vegetarians aleatórias, não sei o critério que o Eclipse realiza essa mudança, porém incomoda demais.

Como eu tiro a função do Eclipse de adicionar `final` nas variáveis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certamente ele não o fez em variáveis aleatórias, ele fez onde cabia fazer e ficava melhor (se o algoritmo e critério que ele usa é bom). Deve ter ligado no Eclipse um mecanismo em que uma das partes do Eclipse refatora seu código para ficar melhor.

Eu não sei se eu desligaria, porque parece que ele está fazendo onde deveria ser `final` mesmo. Tem algum padrão que está usando que deixa claro que elas seriam finais. Não posso garantir que ele não está sendo abusivo, mas pode ser uma forma de aprender onde por `final` por conta própria daqui pra frente. Se a variável é imutável por que não deixar explícito?

Como não uso o Eclipse [tive que recorrer ao SOen para ver como desligar isso](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7147261/221800):

Vá em `project > properties`, `java editor > save actions` e `configure`, `code style`, e finalmente `Use modifier final when possible`.

Ali poderá aprender várias coisas que ele faz e que podem te ajudar programar melhor, ou querer desligar também (ou quem sabe ligar alguma coisa, mas se está desligado por padrão pode não ser uma boa ideia ligar sem entender bem o que acontecerá).

Comment: Então, pensei que ele seguisse uma lógica, porém ele não faz. Ele costuma alterar principalemente várias de metodos atualizados e as vezes métodos que eu não alterei e isso ocorre em um dado momento ele acrescenta`final`outros vezes não. A aleatoriedade acontece isso é um fato. Não somente no meu projeto mais de alguns amigos.
Concordo que as vezes ele aplica de forma correta, porém, já aconteceu de ele aplicar em uma váriavel que acabou ferrando um pacote que ia para produção. 

Esse procedimento já realizei em um package, e não funcionou, porém percebi que não alterou todos os .java.